# ¿Función recursiva sin ciclos?

Tags: vb.net, algoritmos, programación-funcional

Tengo estas dos funciones **Permutaciones** y **CambiarPosiciones** lo que hago con ellas es obtener las combinaciones de una palabra por ejemplo: **dog** entonces tengo {odg, ogd, dgo, gdo, god, dog} todo esta bien ahí, lo que pasa es que me dicen que una función recursiva no debe ir dentro de un ciclo y eso es lo que quiero solucionar, ¿cómo puedo arreglar el método **Permutaciones** para quitarle el ciclo y hacer lo mismo?, aquí dejo los códigos de las funciones:

```
Function Permutaciones(Cadena As String, PosicionUno As Integer, PosicionDos As Integer) As String
    Dim varcadena As String = ""
    Dim i = PosicionUno
    If PosicionUno <> PosicionDos Then
        For i = PosicionUno To PosicionDos
            Cadena = CambiarPosiciones(Cadena, PosicionUno, i)
            Permutaciones(Cadena, PosicionUno + 1, PosicionDos)
            Cadena = CambiarPosiciones(Cadena, PosicionUno, i)
        Next
    Else
        varcadena = "-" + Cadena
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(varcadena)
End Function

Function CambiarPosiciones(ByVal CadenaCambiar As String, PosicionUnoCambiar As Integer, PosicionDosCambiar As Integer)
    Dim Temporal As Char
    Dim VectorChar() = CadenaCambiar.ToCharArray
    Temporal = VectorChar(PosicionUnoCambiar)
    VectorChar(PosicionUnoCambiar) = VectorChar(PosicionDosCambiar)
    VectorChar(PosicionDosCambiar) = Temporal
    Return VectorChar

End Function
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. En principio, la forma que expones aqui es la correcta. Por que te dicen que la funcion recursiva no debe ir dentro de un ciclo? Yo diría que (sin usar LINQ) es complicado librarse del bucle...

Comment: Es correcta porque me da las combinaciones que ocupo, alguien que sabe más me dice no deben haber llamados recursivos dentro de ciclos y por eso estoy buscando la forma de poder quitarlo pero no lo he conseguido.

Comment: Ese es el punto: nunca he oido/leido que llamar a una funcion recursiva dentro de un bucle de problemas o sea un patron incorrecto. Deberias pedir a quien te dijo eso alguna explicación de porque piensa eso. Y como ya te dije,este problema en concreto yo lo resolvería de una manera similar.

Comment: Yo tampoco y lo que encuentro todo lleva un ciclo, pura vida por responder. @Pikoh

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar estas líneas de Código las Cuales te Ayudaran ha Verificar si se establece el array con elementos o no...

```html
Tengo estas dos funciones Permutaciones y CambiarPosiciones lo que hago con ellas es obtener las combinaciones de una palabra por ejemplo: dog entonces tengo {odg, ogd, dgo, gdo, god, dog} todo esta bien ahí, lo que pasa es que me dicen que una función recursiva no debe ir dentro de un ciclo y eso es lo que quiero solucionar, ¿cómo puedo arreglar el método Permutaciones para quitarle el ciclo y hacer lo mismo?, aquí dejo los códigos de las funciones:

Function Permutaciones(Cadena As String, PosicionUno As Integer, PosicionDos As Integer) As String
    Dim varcadena As String = ""
    Dim i = PosicionUno
    If PosicionUno <> PosicionDos Then
        For i = PosicionUno To PosicionDos
            Cadena = CambiarPosiciones(Cadena, PosicionUno, i)
            Permutaciones(Cadena, PosicionUno + 1, PosicionDos)
            Cadena = CambiarPosiciones(Cadena, PosicionUno, i)
        Next
    Else
        varcadena = "-" + Cadena
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(varcadena)
End Function

Function CambiarPosiciones(ByVal CadenaCambiar As String, PosicionUnoCambiar As Integer, PosicionDosCambiar As Integer)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Temporal As Char
    Dim VectorChar() = CadenaCambiar.ToCharArray
    If UBound(VectorChar) = 0 Or Err.Number <> 0 Then ReDim VectorChar(0): VectorChar(0) = "" : Exit Function
    Temporal = VectorChar(PosicionUnoCambiar)
    VectorChar(PosicionUnoCambiar) = VectorChar(PosicionDosCambiar)
    VectorChar(PosicionDosCambiar) = Temporal
    Return VectorChar

End Function
```